# Dynamic conditional cfloop

Tags: coldfusion, conditional-statements, cfloop

Maybe I'm just having a bit of Monday morning brainfreeze here but I have the following code...

```
<cfquery name="getLogins" datasource="myDB">
    SELECT * FROM Logins
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="getLogins">

    <cfset SESSION["#Trim(getLogins.accountName)#LoggedIn"] = 0 />

    <cfloop condition="WHILE SESSION['#Trim(getLogins.accountName)#LoggedIn'] EQUALS 0">
        <cfset getLogins.logInAccount = Application.cfcs.Login.logInAccount(getLogins.accountName,getLogins.email,getLogins.password) />
    </cfloop>

</cfloop>
```

I'm getting an error with my condition to do with the Session variable that I'm referencing but I cannot see what I am doing wrong?

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunno why I had a WHILE in my condition - doh! Problem solved